# Using if function on data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to use panda for data management. So python scans a .tsv with some data in it and using panda convert it into df using headers. I currently have a data frame(df) let's say 'x', of the length 50. I want to know how many numbers in the df are lesser than 5. For this I used:

```
if(len (df1(df1['x']<5))<10)
```

This works just fine. Now I also want to know which elements and their row number in specific amongst the df that are lesser than 5 and print it. I try to print the df saying:

```
 print(df1['x'])
```

But it then prints the entire df and not an individual element. How can I print individual elements and row number for easier data management?

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Is the name of the column x or name of the dataframe x?

Answer (score 0):

To find total elements in column x that are less than 5:

```
(df['x'] < 5).sum()
```

To find index of element which are less than 5 in column x:

```
df[df['x'] < 5].index
```

or Using numpy:

```
list(np.where(df['x'] < 5])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What can I do if I want to print that row? and especially some specific elements

Comment: `print(df[df.index==indexNumber])`

Comment: This shows the header name and not the entry where it is incorrect

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found the problem. Actually the command `list(np.where(df['x'] < 5])` works and gives the actual number of the row with an error. For eg, `[array(5,9,23...1089)]`. However, I am trying to save these results into a log file. In that case, the same command does not save the row number in the .txt file but the value of the element with an error. For eg. `[array (0.234, 0.176, 0.999...0.288)]`. So can you help me how do I save the same row numbers obtained in the results in the log file. It would be great if it could be a .tsv file.